# Modifying a value in a nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a nested object:

```
{
    id: "id",
    name: "Name",
    type: "SC",
    allgemein: {
      charname: "Name",
      spieler: "Jon",
    },
    eigenschaften: {
      lebenspunkte: "30",
    },
    talente: {},
    zauber: {},
  }
```

With my form I'm trying to create a new object. Most of it works, but in the function `handleSubmit`, I'm trying to set the nested `spieler` to `"TEST"`.

```
import React from "react";
    import { TextField, Button } from "@material-ui/core/";

    export default class extends React.Component {
      state = this.getInitState();

      getInitState() {
        const { charakterID } = this.props;

        return charakterID
          ? charakterID
          : {
              name: "",
              allgemein: {
                charname: "",
                spieler: "",
              },
              eigenschaften: {},
              talente: {},
              zauber: {},
            };
      }

      componentWillReceiveProps({ charakterID }) {
        this.setState({
          ...charakterID,
        });
      }

      handleChange = (n) => ({ target: { value } }) => {
        this.setState({
          [n]: value,
        });
      };

      handleChangeAllg = (n) => ({ target: { value } }) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          allgemein: {
            ...prevState.allgemein,
            charname: value,
          },
        }));
      };

      handleSubmit = () => {
        this.props.onSubmit({
          id: this.state.name.toLocaleLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "-"),
          type: "SC",
          allgemein: {spieler: "TEST"},
          ...this.state,
        });

        this.setState(this.getInitState());
      };

      render() {
        const {
            name,
            allgemein: { charname },
          } = this.state,
          { charakterID } = this.props;

        console.log("fired");
        console.log(this.props.onCreate);

        return (
          <form>
            <TextField
              label="name"
              value={name}
              onChange={this.handleChange("name")}
              margin="dense"
              fullWidth
            />
            <br />
            <TextField
              label="charname"
              value={charname}
              onChange={this.handleChangeAllg("charname")}
              margin="dense"
              fullWidth
            />
            <br />
            <Button color="primary" variant="contained" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
              {charakterID ? "Edit" : "Neu"}
            </Button>
          </form>
        );
      }
    }
```

It wont work and I don't know why. Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you be a bit more specific about "it won't work". What result are you expecting, exactly, and what result is this giving? Any errors or is it simply a logical issue? You have a lot of extra code that doesn't appear to relate to the problem, so you might consider removing some of that to make it easier for others to see the problem clearly. See [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: You are missing a e.preventDefault() in handle submit or it will reload your page :) this is the first remark i have

Comment: Ok, I try to explain what i am expecting.
I expect the variable allgemein: { spielter: "Test"}
But i allways get allgemein: { spielter: ""}

Comment: In handleSubmit, you're calling props.onSubmit with spieler = "TEST" but then you do a this.setState(this.getInitState()); and getInitState will set spieler to ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if this works

```
handleSubmit = () => {
        this.props.onSubmit({
          ...this.state, // Changed Position
          id: this.state.name.toLocaleLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "-"),
          type: "SC",
          allgemein: {...this.state.allgemein,spieler: "TEST"},

        });

        this.setState(this.getInitState());
      };
```

Comment: thx for fixing it! but now i have an other problem. in object "allgemein" there are two variables, charname and spieler. befor this, i got  the variable "charname" with the second <TextField>. now its gone

Comment: @Dr.MalteWesterloh, I have updated my answer, check now.